# Change the ACL for already uploaded object to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

We have many objects in Firebase storage, which are already uploaded by an Android device with private ACL.

Is there any possibility that through firebase js SDK we can change the ACL from a web application? I have gone through all available resources but I don't see any valid option for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No.

I actually don't think that those objects have private ACL. [Project private](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#defaultbuckets) I guess is the right term. Objects uploaded through Firebase SDKs inherit the [default acls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) that was automatically added during firebase project creation.

Changing ACLs of a particular object can only be manipulated through cloud console or GCS libraries. If you have tons of objects that needs to be updated, using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) would be your best option.